# Weightpaint colors not visible when material is assigned in Geometry Nodes

Tags: 3d-view, geometry-nodes, weight-painting

I use several weightpaint groups for assigning several objects with a geometry node to a simple plain.That works perfect. But I also want to assign a material to a weightpaint group.

At the moment I connect that material to the *Join Geometry* node, the weightpaint colors dissapear from the viewport.

Is this a bug in Blender or do I need to set something special in the plane, GN-node or viewport?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post some screenshots to illustrate the problem

Comment: Trying to add screenshots, but after <Add picture>, it dissapears again.
No idea why.

Comment: @Rene ...because you added external links to screenshots instead of adding the screenshots to the question.